# For Magento2 how to apply a redirect rewrite in .htaccess file for all URL's from .html to /

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, htaccess, .htaccess, redirect-url

For Magento2 how to apply a rewrite in .htaccess for all URL's from .html to / URL structure. The M1 store has .html as the end, the new M2 store has / as the URL ending for all products and categories.

We have tried the below:

```
############################################
## Redirect .html to /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.]+\.html(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$ 
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

But it breaks the checkout and some other parts of the site. Any ideas on how to correct please? Looks to be https error on checkout I think.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by simply adding rule 
Redirect 301 /abc.html/  /abc/
I have shown you a demo you can change it to your product URL.